Is there a way in VBA to create a button that pulls a random number from a list/table and insert it into another cell?
Let me start this off by saying I have no prior experience with (ActiveX) buttons in Excel, I know my way around excel but never had to work with VBA that much. I am very open to learning so any nudge in the right direction would be great!
I'm working on an excel workbook that simulates the stock market for a game we're playing. For comedic effect, these values don't change predictably but rather are modified using a random number. I have a list of these random numbers and would like to have a button that upon being pressed looks for the bottom-most empty cell in the "Delta" column and pastes a value from the random number list. (see image)
Table example

For another part of this workbook, I've used the function: OFFSET(C3,COUNTA(C3:C48)-1,0) to find the bottommost filled cell in the "Delta" column. Perhaps this could be re-used?
In order to test the button, I tried to create a more simple version that worked for only one cell.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If InStr(1, CommandButton1.Caption, "OFF") Then
        Range("C5").Value = ""
    Else
        Range("C5").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Table3[Delta]"), Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Table3[Delta]"))))
    End If

End Sub

This, however continued to give me "1004" error messages.

How to find the last used row in a table

Where is your random number list?  Is it a regular range or is it a table/listobject?

@TimWilliams It's a table in a separate sheet. A one column table consisting of 26 values

Did you try my suggestion?

@BigBen, thanks! I take it that if I modify the cells.find(), I can also look for an empty cell?

@TimWilliams Not yet, I was about to try it. I am only just back from work.

No need to modify the Find, just use .Offset(1) to refer to the blank row following.

@TimWilliams, your code works, thanks!
I'll try to combine this with the other suggestion by BigBen and see if I can get my ' vision' to work haha

@TimWilliams I managed to get it working, thanks for the help!

@BigBen, thanks for the help. I posted my answer below this question to help any other person that might have the same problem!

Here's an example of how to fetch a random value from a listobject/table column or a regular range:
Dim rng As Range
    
'reference the source range with the numbers
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Random") _
            .ListObjects("List1").ListColumns("Nums").DataBodyRange

'...or a regular range
'Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Random").Range("A2:A50") 'for example

'pick a random number              
Debug.Print rng.Cells(Application.RandBetween(1, rng.Cells.Count)).Value


Thank you Tim Williams and Big Ben for the help
Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Randomiser").Range("A2:A27")

'Find empty cell in Delta column (Lancaster Airways)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Lancaster Airways")
emptycell = ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns(3).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1).Row
'testrun
Debug.Print rng.Cells(Application.RandBetween(1, rng.Cells.Count)).Value
Debug.Print emptycell

'printing time
ws.Cells(emptycell, 3) = rng.Cells(Application.RandBetween(1, rng.Cells.Count)).Value

End Sub

